# Преобразование строки в кодировке utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8

Есть строка вида `'\u041c\u0422\u0421_WSD'`, где первые три символа это русские буквы МТС и далее идет _WSD на английском. Как правильно это преобразовать в "читабильный" вид.

Мой код:

```
s = '\u041c\u0422\u0421_WSD'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

Если разложить по частям:

```
# кодируем в bytes
s = '\u041c\u0422\u0421_WSD'.encode('utf-8')
# декодируем в строку
s = s.decode('utf-8')
```

У меня огромный пробел с "кодировками" по этому не понимаю как данное преобразование работает. Помогите пожалуйста разораться кто сталкивался с этим.

Comment: Что вас смущает? https://ideone.com/x7zi5D

Comment: Она и есть в читабельном виде, просто берите и выводите её куда вам надо (в консоль, в файл, куда угодно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша строка уже в кодировке UTF-8. Просто некоторые символы записаны не в явном виде, а через их код. Это видно, например, при сравнении:

```
'МТС_WSD' == '\u041c\u0422\u0421_WSD'  # True
```

Тем более нет никакого смысла в этих действиях:

```
s = '\u041c\u0422\u0421_WSD'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

Т.к. в результате строка никак не меняется.

Comment: О как))) даже не попробовал) А как называется это представление?

Comment: Вот таблица символов. https://unicode-table.com/ru Там у каждого символа есть номер в 16сс, например, U+0035. В Питоне можно написать '\u0035', чтобы получить этот символ, это будет цифра 5.

Comment: Я не правильно задал вопрос) есть не строка а файл в котором строки так представлены, собственно когда его считываешь нужно получить читабельный вид.

Comment: @garrythehotdog, задайте лучше новый вопрос тогда